# how B-tree indexing works in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, search, b-tree

When I create an index for a table in mysql, I see that the index_type is type `BTREE`. Now although  I understand about btree(s), I do not quiet understand how it stores the index and how the database searches the records based on this.

I mean, btree is excellent for databases to perform read and writes large blocks of data, 
when we create an index for column type of `Primary key`, what I understand is, it creates a tree and splitting the values for the root based on the value type of the root.

Now, does it store only the the primary key `ID` under the trees or the whole data associated with that primary key?

After finding the wanted primary ID, how does the database extract the record?

Answer (score 30):

The database stores the value indexed as a `B-Tree` key, and the record pointer as a `B-Tree` value.

Whenever you search for a record holding a certain value of an indexed column, the engine locates the key holding this value in the `B-Tree`, retrieves the pointer to the record and fetches the record.

What exactly is a "record pointer", depends on the storage engine.

- In `MyISAM`, the record pointer is an offset to the record in the `MYI` file.
- In `InnoDB`, the record pointer is the value of the `PRIMARY KEY`.

In `InnoDB`, the table itself is a `B-Tree` with a `PRIMARY KEY` as a `B-Tree` key. This is what called a "clustered index" or "index-organized table". In this case, all other fields are stored as a `B-Tree` value.

In `MyISAM`, the records are stored without any special order. This is called "heap storage".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In my  database i have some tables with MyISAM and some as InnoDB with indexes on them. Will this in anyway effect the joins and queries I write is both are different types?

Comment: @JPro: The database handles the underlying indexing details automatically. The `JOIN` syntax is the same for `MyISAM` and `InnoDB` tables.

Comment: what i mean is, does it matter at all to create all the tables with same storage engine or not?

Comment: @JPro: you can mix the different engines in one query freely. Be aware, however, that `MyISAM` has no transaction support and when using multiple tables in a same `DML` query which you later rollback, be aware that the rollback will not affect changes to `MyISAM` tables. But, again, in a `SELECT` query, it's perfectly ok to mix both engines.

Comment: just final question. I see in my mysql folder, 2 types of files (.frm and .myd), .myd files are bigger than .frm files. I guess .frm used by btrees. How does the data gets stored in to these file ? If the database wants to search any record, does it just open the file and search the tree?

Comment: @JPro: `FRM` is the table description, is contains no data. For `MyISAM`, the table data are contained in `MYD` fileds, the index data are contained in `MYI` files. For `InnoDB`, the table data are contained in the `InnoDB` tablespaces, which can be shared (all tables and indexes reside in a single file in the root of the data directory), or per-table (table and all of its indexes reside in a single `ibd` file in the database directory)

Answer (score 3):

MySQL InnoDB is actually using B+Tree which add more features than B-Tree.

Such as:

Only leaves node has values to allow more keys in the same page node to reduce tree high which will reduce I/O count.

Add a bidirectional pointer in each leaf node to make range search faster

**B-Tree**

[image: B-Tree]

**B+Tree**

[image: B+Tree]

Comment: It would be intersting to know what the btree+ keys are. Creating an index over a single int is obvious but what if a string or multiple attributes are used? how is the btree+ key calculated?

Comment: If it is string then the key will be string. multiple column is same, store as string in the order of the column when creating index