# Creating a MySQL index on a Varchar always makes 2 indexes?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, optimization, indexing

I have an `email` column in my table which is a `VARCHAR(255)`. Most emails would only be 40-50 characters long, and the rest of the characters are there just there for a rare case. Therefore, I want to only index the first 50 characters of the email column.

I've tried to do it with this query:

```
ALTER TABLE  `users` ADD INDEX (email(50) )
```

However, that creates 2 indexes, one named `email` and the other `email_2`. The first index has no length limits, the second one has got the 50 character limit.

Why is this? Is there any workaround or do I have no option but to index the full column?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why bother indexing only the first 50 characters? MySQL will be smart enough to only use space in the index for the actual data. I.e., it isn't going to allocate 255 characters of space for each entry. Thus, there is no reason not to simply index the entire column as it is.

Comment: The table will have a large number of records and many inserts happening e.g because user accounts are imported from address books, would you still say there's no need?

Comment: @Click Upvote - Yes I would. Whether you use the first 50 characters or the entire column, the fundamental issues with indexes will still apply. You are making a small sacrifice in write performance for larger gains in read performance. It is always a trade-off. If you were using a `char` instead of `varchar`, there might be more of an issue in keeping down the size of the index. However, MySQL is smart enough with `varchar` to only index the actual data.

Comment: thanks - last question, would you say a char with a partial index would be better than using a varchar, or is a varchar with an index better?

Comment: @Click Upvote - First, this starts to smell of premature optimization. The simpler solution is a single index on email since, presumably, you are doing searches on email addresses. Second, as with any performance change, the only way to know is to do tests that give you metrics about the performance difference. Last, I would say that the issues with dealing with a partial index better more than outweigh its costs which is unlikely. Thus, my inclination would be to use a single index on email unless I had hard data that compelled me to look for a better solution.

Comment: @Click Upvote - It depends. *If* we are comparing two columns of the same size and *if* there is a ton of data (10's of millions of rows if not 100's of millions), and *if* all other factors are equal (like data integrity to what is being stored), a char might be fractionally faster than a varchar. Of course, the only way to know for sure is to actually run tests. On the whole, my gut says that choosing between the two purely for performance reasons will not make any noticeable difference.

Comment: @Thomas, Your advice is unorthodox and I'd go as far as to say that it's completely wrongly. Indexes need to be stored and it's common usage to prefix indexes to reduce storage, especially so for names and name-esque columns like emails. Yes, especially so for emails where a vast majority of rows are going to end with repeated chars like `~@gmail.com`, `~@yahoo.com`, `~@yet-another-domain.com` etc. Every char added  to the index incurs one extra char of index storage **per row**. If `email` is a primary index and there are additional... *[cont]*

Comment: .....secondary index(es) for that table, then it's not just "per row", but **per row per extra secondary index**. The only situation where it doesn't matter how much is allocated to the index is when the index is clustered **and** it's the only index in the entire table. Related: https://www.percona.com/files/presentations/percona-live/london-2011/PLUK2011-b-tree-indexes-and-innodb.pdf ,  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-index-types.html , http://stackoverflow.com/a/2362693/632951

Comment: Actually, my advice was to _test_ to see if there is a discernable difference. Keep in mind that there is a performance hit for MySQL to maintain the logic of the truncation. In the grander scheme the difference is only going to be noticible at very large database sizes. Thus, that advice not even remotely unorthodox. *Test* to see if there is a difference. However, in testing, the null hypothesis should be to take the simplest route.

Comment: @Thomas, Referring to permanent storage here and not CPU cycles. That extra (one?) CPU cycle for truncation takes **zero** storage. The amount of storage needed is a deductive answer. The number calculated is either right, or it's wrong; either way the conclusion is guaranteed and independent of the chipset used thus there's nothing to measure.

Comment: [cont] It's like asking does a file with `x` number of bytes take more storage or does a file with `y` number of bytes take more storage. The answer is deducible and reasonably independent of the execution environment.


[cont] Besides, real databases like MySQL are meant to store bulk information and discussions on MySQL will thus assume such scenarios by default. If we're only storing several thousands of rows, sure, nothing is stopping us from storing all ints as doubles and all doubles as strings.

Comment: @Pacerier - You are ignoring the actual question: _Does it matter?_ The index truncated at 50 chars has to handle situations where 51 characters are stored. So, yes, there is a slight additional element of logic in handling truncation. It is likely that an index on all 255 of a varchar will perform exactly the same as one on 50 characters since most of the time they will take the same amount of storage. Without testing, there is no way to be sure but unless I had definitive evidence to suggest that a filtered index performed better, the simplest solution is to just index the entire column.