# MySQL configuration recommendation

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-5.1

I have a really small script that takes some parameters from the request headers and sends a single `INSERT` query to a db hosted on localhost.

The DB has one table and I do not run any kind of reporting or anything, so basically 100% of the queries to this server are `INSERT` queries.

The script is being heavily accessed so I get a lot of these queries running concurrently.

I'm looking for ways to tweak the config file to support my specific needs.

**EDIT**

I'm currently seeing these variables on phpMyAdmin->status that seems high:

```
Slow_queries 22
Handler_read_rnd 1,496 k
Handler_read_rnd_next 111M
Created_tmp_disk_tables 495
Sort_merge_passes 77
Opened_tables 332
Table_locks_waited 154
```

The reason I'm asking is because I'm going to get a lot more concurrent connections soon and I want to make the tweaks before so the server can handle it.

Comment: Do you have any performance problems ? (load too high ?)

Comment: If the table is **never** read, what's the point in it?

Comment: @eggyal I'm storing the data and once every couple of weeks export it entirely and load it to another system - on the other system is where I do other queries on the data.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've told us, the only recommandation I have for you is to convert your table to use InnoDB engine, if it currently uses another engine. The reason for this is that, in InnoDB, `INSERT`s are very fast (the rows are stored in the order of the primary key, so they're basically just appended to the end of the table).

Comment: OK.. I'm currently using MyISAM - how much of a difference should I expect after changing this to InnoDB?

Comment: @Sobolan that cant be right. MyISAM and InnoDB are very different internally. So if I have a email address as a primary key in InnoDB it is going to append it to the end? Not a chance. InnoDB stores its information in a btree. Thus it will place the email address to where it fits in the order of the primary key. MyIsam works differently see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362667/how-b-tree-indexing-works-in-mysql

Comment: Also read this http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/06/difference-between-innodb-and-myisam.html InnoDB is great for ACID complaint tables but in your case MyISAM probably makes more sense. Essentially in a MyISAM table records are always appended at the end. A MyISAM is a heap with the primary key being a index on top of the heap. This makes it fast for logging data. However the two are extremely different. In a InnoDB data is stored in the order of the primary key. In a MyISAM it is appended at the end with a index on top pointing to the record position in the MyISAM file.

Comment: @Namphibian I assumed he had a primary key that is an auto-incrementing ID. Maybe that's not the case, but if it is, then the `INSERT`s will indeed just append to the end of the table. And InnoDB doesn't store its information in BTrees. Some types of indexes are represented as BTrees, true, but it's a completely different thing.

Comment: @SoboLABN. I agree with your statement dont get me wrong InnoDB might be fasters. It depends. However when you create a primary key on a InnoDB it is stored as a b-tree on disk. The MySQL documentation states: All data in InnoDB is stored in database pages that make up a B-tree index (the clustered index organized according to the primary key columns). Here is the link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-row-format.html